# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found when a numeric was expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below two tables created.

```
CREATE TABLE DELETE_CUSTOM
(
 column1 varchar2(30),
 column2 varchar2(30)
)

CREATE TABLE DELETE_CUSTOM_HIST
(
 column1 varchar2(30),
 column2 varchar2(30),
 ARCHIVAL_DATE DATE
)
```

I used to insert data into `DELETE_CUSTOM_HIST` like below.

```
INSERT INTO DELETE_CUSTOM_HIST
      (SELECT DE.*, to_date('12/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')
         FROM DELETE_CUSTOM DE);
```

Now, I had to add a new column to both the tables.

```
ALTER TABLE DELETE_CUSTOM ADD column3 VARCHAR2(30);
ALTER TABLE DELETE_CUSTOM_HIST ADD column3 VARCHAR2(30);
```

If I try to insert data to `DELETE_CUSTOM_HIST` table with the same below INSERT statementm,
I am getting ORA-01858 error.

```
INSERT INTO DELETE_CUSTOM_HIST
      (SELECT DE.*, to_date('12/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')
         FROM DELETE_CUSTOM DE);
--ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found when a numeric was expected.
```

What change I need to do to my INSERT statement to overcome this issue.

Note : The above insert statement is in PLSQL package. The above two tables are actually having
       many columns. I have just mentioned few columns to explain my problem in a simple way.

Comment: Why not use a trigger on `DELETE_CUSTOM` table instead of doing a `SELECT` query?

Comment: The problem here is that you are lazy to make changes in your code to write all the columns. Looks like someone before you ( or yourself ) has carelessly written the package/procedure by including `select * from` everywhere  in the inserts and now you are supposed to make changes in all those places. I would recommend you to make this code change as a one time activity, so that your future job becomes much simpler, i.e whenever a new column is added, you would simply have to add it in the code. That's a  much better practice.

Comment: Just FYI, you can use this `DATE'2017-12-31'` (an ANSI DATE literal) instead of this `to_date('12/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO DELETE_CUSTOM_HIST(column1,column2,column3)
      (SELECT de.column1,de.column2,de.column3, 
to_date('12/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')
         FROM DELETE_CUSTOM DE);
```

explicitly write column list and try again.

Comment: This is a straight forward approach.As I mentioned, I have many columns in the table. So, I was looking a better way in which column names are not explicitly mentioned.

Comment: I could even drop the tables and recreate it to match my INSERT statement.

Comment: create table delete_custom_hist as select * from delete_custom . create second table again then add archival_date column. Then try again. But before change your existing delete_custom_hist table name, if you dont want lose data in it.

Comment: Explicitly listing column names **is** the better way. You wouldn't want to drop and recreate the tables each time you need to add a column.

Answer (score 1):

you have :

```
CREATE TABLE DELETE_CUSTOM_HIST
(
 column1 varchar2(30),
 column2 varchar2(30),
 ARCHIVAL_DATE DATE,
 column3 varchar2(30)
);
```

trying to `INSERT`

a `varchar2` type column ( `COLUMN3` column of `DELETE_CUSTOM` table ) column to

a `date` type column ( `ARCHIVAL_DATE` column of `DELETE_CUSTOM_HIST` table ).

The raised error is due to this mismatch with `varchar2` and `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Two points.  The first is to always list the columns explicitly for such statements.  Don't use `*` in production code -- unless you really know what you are doing.

```
INSERT INTO DELETE_CUSTOM_HIST (column1, column2, column3, archival_date)
     SELECT DE.column1, DE.column2, DE.column3, DATE '2017-12-31'
     FROM DELETE_CUSTOM DE;
```

Notes (in addition to listing the columns):

- Parentheses are not appropriate around the `SELECT`.
- Use date literals.  Oracle supports the ANSI standard here, use it.
- Are you sure you just want the date portion for the archival date?